# How is a PDO result set stored

Tags: php, pdo

I've been studying PHP for 2 months now as my first scripting language. For most of my problems i can easily find an answer online, but there's something about PDO that i can't seem to understand.

In order to retrieve data from a database I instantiate a new object of the PDO class and call the PDO::query() method on it. This returns a PDOStatement object which carries the result set from the SQL query. Here's where the problem starts. I can't seem to understand how and where the data from the result set is stored.

In the PHP Manual i learned to display the returned rows by **iterating over the PDOStatement object** with a foreach loop. However, the PHP manual clearly states that if an object is converted to an array, the result is an array whose elements are the **object's properties**. The PDOStatement only has **one property** - $queryString - containing the issued query string. So... where are the query results stored? And why can I reach them through an array with a foreach loop, but not outside of it?

```
// Instantiate new PDO object to establish a new connection with MySQL database
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbhost=localhost;dbname=world', 'root', 'secret');

// Execute SQL query - Returns a PDOStatement object
$result = $db->query("SELECT Name, Continent, Population FROM Country");


// Result set can be accessed with a foreach loop iterating over the PDOStatement object
foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "$row[Name] - $row[Continent] - $row[Population] <br />";
}

// Outside the foreach loop, $result cannot be accessed this way.
// This produces 'Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array'
echo $result[0]['Name'];
```

Comment: It implements the [`Iterator`](http://php.net/Iterator) interface, so that an implicit method call returns the individual results; so they don't have to be present as properties or internal data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PDOStatement class implements the [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php), which lets its objects be iterated through.

```
Iterator extends Traversable {
    /* Methods */
    abstract public mixed current ( void )
    abstract public scalar key ( void )
    abstract public void next ( void )
    abstract public void rewind ( void )
    abstract public boolean valid ( void )
}
```

---

For an object that implements the Iterator interface,

```
foreach($result as $row) {
    // Code
}
```

is equivalent to

```
for ($result->rewind(); $result->valid(); $result->next()) {
    $row = $result->current();
    // Code
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I took the time to learn about SPL and the Iterator interface in particular. Now I see how it's possible to iterate over the object, but I still don't understand where the result set from the query is stored. I've learned that objects can only have tree types of members: properties, methods and constants. If the result set is not stored in a property, then where is it stored? Is there some kind of buffer?

Comment: Interesting question. I'd expect the PDOStatement object hold a resource, the same type of resource that mysql_query returns. However, according to http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php it doesn't.

Comment: Also, my answer was slightly wrong. PDOStatement directly implements `Traversable`, which is an internal class extended by `Iterator`.